# How to prepare testing data for object detection?

Tags: python, testing, computer-vision, classification

I have some images with which I will test an object detection classifier.

I'll have the classifier output the coordinates for the rectangles where it believes the target objects are, but I wonder how the results are tested?

I'm guessing I should have a reference file of coordinates of true object positions against which I can compare the classifier's results.

**What if the classifier does make a correct classification, just with the coordinates not exactly the same as the ones in the reference file?**

How's this usually solved?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends of the method you are going to use. One of them you've proposed, and in that case I would put an fixed possible error rate for bad detecting case which, if the classifier result lays inside the error interval for one of the examples from data test file, is considered as a proper classified example. Of course this fixed error rate should be as small as not to "overdetect" in the data set.

I would suggest trying [cross-validation](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/iss/iss_l13.pdf) as a technique to test classifier. From data set, it chooses some vectors (images) as a test set and the rest of them as a training set. Repeat few times and average the errors resulting in estimated classificator error. And you don't have to have separate data test set and you don't have to worry about the problem you stated.